# starting JSOM workflows 2013 Invalid request / unauthorised

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow, javascript, jsom

I have trouble starting workflows with JSOM.
 The first case causes errors only for some users mostly on Wi-Fi
 First case is :

```
var servicesManager = new         SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager(context, web);
var subscriptions = servicesManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().enumerateSubscriptionsByList(ListGUId);
context.load(servicesManager);
context.load(subscriptions);
context.executeQueryAsync(succesFunction, failFunction);
```

this throws

> "Invalid querry Exception : Invalid request"

Now I'm using:

```
var servicesManager = new SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager(context, web);
var workflowDeploymentService = servicesManager.getWorkflowDeploymentService();
var publishedWorkflowDefinitions = workflowDeploymentService.enumerateDefinitions(true);
context.load(servicesManager);
context.load(publishedWorkflowDefinitions);
context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
var workflowGUId = publishedWorkflowDefinitions.get_data()[0].get_id(); 
var workflowSub = servicesManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().enumerateSubscriptionsByDefinition(workflowGUId);
context.load(workflowSub);
context.executeQueryAsync(succesFunction, failFunction);
},failFunction);
```

And this one gives me

> "Unauthorised error"

and can be successfuly run only with Full Control or Design permissions.

Can is solve this somehow without using SPService?